# Creating a Git repository on a server in LAN environment

Tags: git

I have setup a git repository on a local server (windows server 2008). We are a team of 3-4 developers and wants to clone this repository on our local machine.

On some other posts, I read that ssh or git daemon can be used for this. But I do not have clear understanding of what to use and how.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need some daemon which will handle push and pulls. I recommend to use [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) for this. It comes with such a daemon and it provides many other features like a nice Web frontend, access control, code review, etc. You can deploy Gitlab on your own Server, see [here](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/), or you can test it, see [here](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/). It is like your private Github.

If you rely on Windows Server you could install [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) and use the official [Gitlab docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/). To the best of my knowledge, running a Git server on Windows is very difficult.

Another solution could be to put a bare repository on a file share. You can push and pull into the repository but you don't have good access control.

Comment: I don't think Gitlab provides an edition for windows

Comment: Do you know, whether the version with the file share prevents data corruption, if multiple developers try to push their changes to the repo?

Comment: Could question. I assume it does not because the local Git client writes to the share and if multiple clients write at the same time they will corrupt the repo. But this is only a guess.